# Importing Excel data to a already established SQL DB visual basic

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, excel

I have developed a program in which all data is entered into a SQL DB. the program has been designed in Visual Studio using Visual Basic. I am now getting external data supplied in an excel format and need to know how to import the excel data into the SQL DB and ensure the data goes into the appropriate columns. I have set a template up for them with standard excel headers and I open and view the data into a datagridview before the import but the last part which is the import function to SQL I have not yet worked out.

Any help would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific problem that you're having?

A better bet might be to use SSIS to import the data. It's what SSIS is made to do.